# Fluent NHibernate MySQL batching

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I need to apply batch sizing to my NHibernate Sessions. I am using MySQL.

After finding out, that NHibernate doesn't natively support batch sizing for MySQL I installed this package:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.MySQLBatcher

which contains a batcher for MySQL.

Then I was searching for the point where I can inject the batcher and found this:

[Why doesn't NHibernate support batching on MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900594/why-doesnt-nhibernate-support-batching-on-mysql)

According to the accepted answer I don't find something like this `DataBaseIntegration()` method.

Has anyone got through this before?

Comment: I think the 4 branch will now have mysql embedded, probably not going to help you now but always good to point out for future. https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt#L100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this package and it worked for me.

Below the configuration I used:

```
var cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionProvider, "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, "NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver");
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, "NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect");
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseSecondLevelCache, "false");
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseQueryCache, "false");
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.GenerateStatistics, "false");
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CommandTimeout, "300");
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BatchSize, "1000");
cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BatchStrategy,  typeof(MySqlClientBatchingBatcherFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

Comment: Thank you, will check this on monday ;)

Answer (score 2):

If using mapping by code syntax then my set up for batching in MySql looks like this (NH 3.3+):-

```
var configure = new Configuration().Configure();
configure.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
    {
        x.Dialect<MySQL5Dialect>();
        x.ConnectionStringName = "db";
        x.BatchSize = 50;
        x.Batcher<MySqlClientBatchingBatcherFactory>();

    })
    .Cache(x => x.UseQueryCache = true)
    .CurrentSessionContext<WebSessionContext>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If using FluentNhibernate, my mapping code might help you:

```
Dim fConfig As FluentConfiguration
...
fConfig.ExposeConfiguration(Function(x) x.DataBaseIntegration(Sub(y)
         y.Batcher(Of MySQLBatcher.MySqlClientBatchingBatcherFactory)()
         y.BatchSize = 100
     End Sub)
```